# GCC and -fsanitize=leak

Tags: g++, memory-leak-detector

I'm working and on a large C++ project and making it compile with clang would be painful, so I'm stuck with GCC.

I want to use the nice `-fsanitize=leak` flag that I already used with clang on a previous job, but it does not seem to work.

I made a very simple example to test it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
void FooBar() {
  malloc(7);
}
int main() {
  FooBar();
  return 0;
}
```

With clang it works as expected:

```
>> clang -fsanitize=leak main.cpp
>> LSAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out
=================================================================
==18052==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
Direct leak of 7 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
#0 0x41dcbc  (~/dev/addresssanitizertest/a.out+0x41dcbc)
#1 0x431ac3  (~/dev/addresssanitizertest/a.out+0x431ac3)
#2 0x431ae3  (~/dev/addresssanitizertest/a.out+0x431ae3)
#3 0x7f8077e71a3f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x20a3f)
SUMMARY: LeakSanitizer: 7 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
>>
```

But with gcc it does not seem to detect anything:

```
>> gcc -fsanitize=leak main.cpp
>> LSAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out
>>
```

Did I miss something like a nice environment variable? Did someone ever made it work with gcc?

**EDIT**: This works for instance:

```
g++ -fsanitize=address main.cpp
ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1 ./a.out
```

But I can't do that: the perf drawback is too much. I only want leak detection.

Comment: Making your code platform independent is an effort that will pay off in the long run. Making it compatible with clang is a first step in the right direction. Go ahead ;-)

Comment: I agree, and it's usually not so long/hard to do it. And in some cases, Clang found some interesting warnings in your code that gcc doesn't see

Comment: I do agree with you guys, but we have some features that clang have trouble with, like assembly code.

Comment: Did I miss a mention of the gcc version in your post? gcc-5 seems to do what you want.

Comment: Indeed I did not precise that. I use GCC 4.9. I'll try GCC 5 asap!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved it with gcc 5.1 (I was using 4.9).

EDIT: it looks like 5.2 does not work either
EDIT2: it does not work with the gcc provided with ubuntu 15.10 (5.2.1), however I recompiled a 5.2.0 from sources and it worked fine. I really have no clue.

Comment: It does work for me. If it does not work for you, you should report a bug to your distribution (if you installed a pre-compiled gcc) or directly to gcc if you compiled it from source.

Comment: Which version do you use? With the gcc (5.1.1) provided with ubuntu 15.04 it's fine, but I can't make it work with gcc 5.2.1 (ubuntu 15.10). I compiled a gcc 5.1 on an ubuntu 15.10 and it was fine, so I really think it's a regression. I'll try with a recompiled 5.2 just to be sure.

Comment: I am using 5.2.1 from debian testing. Please report this issue to Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm having a look at compilation optins for gcc first

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (with Ubuntu 15.04 and gcc 4.9.2).

Using `ldd` I noticed that `liblsan.so` was not linked, so here how I fixed it :

1) Force linking during compilation

`>> gcc -fsanitize=leak main.cpp -llsan`

2) Execute with

`./a.out`

Answer (score 2):

You must read this and use the patch :

https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2013-11/msg01874.html

Comment: Nice, it seems that the sanitizer is the same that Clang. I've found a blog post about how to use it with Qt, it should be pretty close to use it without Qt : https://blog.qt.io/blog/2013/04/17/using-gccs-4-8-0-address-sanitizer-with-qt/